# How to change a css after selector for a specific id

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-selectors, css-animations

I am trying to change the code such that when I hover on #btnSaveChanges, it will change with background color blue instead of black. Similar with #btnLogout.

HTML

```html
<button id="btnSaveChanges" className="button-57" onClick={handleSave}>
  <span>Save</span>
  <span>Save</span>
</button>
<button id='btnLogout' className="button-57" onClick={handleLogout}>
  <span>Logout</span>
  <span>Logout</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```css
.button-57 {
  position            : relative;
  overflow            : hidden;
  border              : 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  border-radius       : 20px;
  color               : #18181a;
  display             : inline-block;
  font-size           : 15px;
  line-height         : 15px;
  padding             : 18px 18px 17px;
  text-decoration     : none;
  cursor              : pointer;
  background          : #fff;
  user-select         : none;
  -webkit-user-select : none;
  touch-action        : manipulation;
  width               : 45%;
  margin              :10px;
  }
.button-57 span:first-child {
  position   : relative;
  transition : color 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  z-index    : 10;
  }
.button-57 span:last-child {
  color       : white;
  display     : block;
  position    : absolute;
  bottom      : 0;
  transition  : all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  z-index     : 100;
  opacity     : 0;
  top         : 50%;
  left        : 50%;
  transform   : translateY(225%) translateX(-50%);
  height      : 14px;
  line-height : 13px;
  }
.button-57:after{
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : -50%;
  left             : 0;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : black;
  transform-origin : bottom center;
  transition       : transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform        : skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index          : 50;
  }
.button-57:hover:after,
.button-57:active:after {
  transform-origin : bottom center;
  transform        : skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(2);
  }
.button-57:hover span:last-child,
.button-57:active span:last-child {
  transform  : translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  opacity    : 1;
  transition : all 900ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  }
```

Hence I tried adding these classes, but it didn't work, instead the animation didn't trigger.

```css
.button-57#btnSaveChanges::after{
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : -50%;
  left             : 0;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : #2140D9;
  transform-origin : bottom center;
  transition       : transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform        : skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index          : 50;
  }
.button-57#btnLogout:after{
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : -50%;
  left             : 0;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : #db2020;
  transform-origin : bottom center;
  transition       : transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform        : skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index          : 50;
  }
```

The animation didn't trigger.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `!important` rule to the `transform` on `.button-57:hover:after`.

```css
.button-57 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #18181a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 18px 18px 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.button-57 span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  transition: color 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  z-index: 10;
}

.button-57 span:last-child {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(225%) translateX(-50%);
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

.button-57:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform: skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index: 50;
}

.button-57:hover span:last-child,
.button-57:active span:last-child {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
}

 .button-57#btnSaveChanges::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2140D9;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform: skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index: 50;
}

.button-57#btnLogout:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #db2020;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform: skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index: 50;
}

.button-57:hover:after,
.button-57:active:after {
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform: skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(2) !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSaveChanges" class="button-57" onClick={handleSave}><span>Save</span><span>Save</span></button>
<button id='btnLogout' class="button-57" onClick={handleLogout}><span>Logout</span><span>Logout</span></button>
```

Comment: Can you explain why adding !important is making it work. Why was it causing the issue?

Comment: @TimeKiller Because you have `scale` on `.button-57#btnLogout:after` which is overriding the other scale you have set for the `:hover` state.

Comment: @TimeKiller get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [**Kameron's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75942402/how-to-change-a-css-after-selector-for-a-specific-id#75942470) approach, you might consider to **lower specificity** of your rules.

```
 .button-57#btnSaveChanges::after{}
```

Has a super high specificity – especially due to the **ID selector**.
Instead, you could add a second class name to the buttons e.g

```
<button id="btnSaveChanges" class="button-57 btnSaveChanges">
```

```css
.button-57 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #18181a;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 18px 18px 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.button-57 span:first-child {
  position: relative;
  transition: color 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  z-index: 10;
}

.button-57 span:last-child {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(225%) translateX(-50%);
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 13px;
}

.button-57:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
  transform: skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(0);
  z-index: 50;
}

.button-57:hover span:last-child,
.button-57:active span:last-child {
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 900ms cubic-bezier(0.48, 0, 0.12, 1);
}

 .btnSaveChanges::after {
  background-color: #2140D9;
}

.btnLogout:after {
  background-color: #db2020;
}

.button-57:hover:after,
.button-57:active:after {
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform: skewY(9.3deg) scaleY(2);
}
```

```html
<button id="btnSaveChanges" class="button-57 btnSaveChanges">
  <span>Save</span>
  <span>Save</span>
</button>
<button id='btnLogout' class="button-57 btnLogout">
  <span>Logout</span>
  <span>Logout</span>
</button>
```

#### Further reading

[Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
[Strategies for Keeping CSS Specificity Low](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-keeping-css-specificity-low/)